# How to pass op_kwargs to Airflow TaskFlow DAG and Task?

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

Say I have a simple TaskFlow style DAG.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from typing import Dict

@dag(   start_date=datetime.now(),
        schedule_interval='@once',
        catchup=False)
def example_taskflow_api():
    
    @task()
    def extract(value=666) -> Dict[str, int]:
        order_data= {"1001": 301.27, "1002": 433.21, "1003": value}
        return order_data
    
   extract()
my_dag = example_taskflow_api()
```

In the "old" style I might pass some kwarg values, or via the airflow ui, to the operator such as:

```
t1 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id='extract',
    python_callable=extract,
    op_kwargs={"value":777},
    dag=dag,
    )
```

But I cannot find any reference in the [tutorial or docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html) for how to achieve a similar result using TaskFlow style. The [last section of the tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html) mentions Airflow context arguments, but not optionals.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the arguments like any other python method:

```py
extract(value=777)
```

If you want to pass a dict kwargs:

```py
extract(**{"value": 777})
```

If you want to pass a variable from run config, you have to options:

```py
# option 1: provide as argument
extract("{{ dag_run.conf.get('value') }}") # it will be string
# option 2
@task()
def extract(**context) -> Dict[str, int]:
    order_data= {"1001": 301.27, "1002": 433.21, "1003": context["dag_run"].conf.get('value')} # you load the variable in its initial type
    return order_data
```

Comment: Is there where extract(value=666) is defined or at where its called in the taskflow extract(), as in my example. As the latter does not work - I'm trying to work out how I would pass different arguments e.g. {"value":888} when the DAG is ran. i.e. I will leave 666 as the default, but be able to pass different values for different runs

Comment: you want to pass it from where exactly?

Comment: I just updated my answer to provide some example to read the argument from run config.